# A-frame convert zip package into glb for sketch fab model

Tags: model, aframe, virtual-reality, gltf

I've been coding In A-frame recently and I've been using gltf models in my scene. I've been using tinkercad models because I can't figure out how to put sketchfab.com models in my code. When I download a model from sketchfab.com and press download as gltf, it gives me a zip folder. Inside the zip folder are 2 files and a folder. Scene.glf and scene.bin are the files and textures is the folder. I want to take this zip folder and turn it into a sole glb or gltf file. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

For others' context, Sketchfab returns something like...

- `model/scene.gltf`
- `model/scene.bin`
- `model/textures/diffuse.png`
- `model/textures/normal.png`

... where the `scene.gltf` file contains relative references to the other files. A-Frame can load all of those files given just the `.gltf` reference, [as documented](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/primitives/a-gltf-model.html#sidebar), as long as they're hosted in your project under a similar folder structure:

```html
<a-gltf-model src="assets/model/scene.gltf"></a-gltf-model>
```

It's also common to combine the whole model into a self-contained (binary) `.glb` file, which is a "lossless" change and should not affect the content in any way if done by a correctly-implemented tool. Two easy options would be [glTF-Pipeline](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/gltf-pipeline) or [glTF-Transform](https://gltf-transform.donmccurdy.com/). Example:

```
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli

gltf-transform cp model/scene.gltf output.glb
```

Also see https://glb-packer.glitch.me/, but it may not work with certain files.

> ***NOTICE:** While it's technically possible to create a self-contained `.gltf` file, rather than `.glb`, don't do this. Embedding binary resources in a (JSON) `.gltf` file adds 20-30% to file size and reduces loading speed. The (binary) `.glb` format is more efficient here.*